# Why Qxd5 instead of Rxd5?

Tags: puzzles, zwischenzug, fork

[This puzzle](https://chesstempo.com/chess-problems/83555470) on [chesstempo](https://chesstempo.com/) caught my eye. We play as Black:

```
[FEN "1r1r2k/p4pp/2q/2p1p2P/P1P1Pn/B3NP/4Q2P/R6K w - - 0 1"]

1. Nd5
```

The White queen is under attack, yet one shall not rush and capture it. The White may fork the Black king and queen and then fork two rooks:

```
[FEN "1r1r2k/p4pp/2q/2p1p2P/P1P1Pn/B3NP/4Q2P/R6K w - - 0 1"]

1. Nd5 Nxe2 
2. Ne7+ Kf8 
3. Nxc6 Ke8 
4. Nxb8 Rxb8
```

So, we lose a rook here. Therefore, we need to capture the knight. I took the knight with the rook:

```
[FEN "1r1r2k/p4pp/2q/2p1p2P/P1P1Pn/B3NP/4Q2P/R6K w - - 0 1"]

1. Nd5 Rxd5
```

Yet, [chesstempo](https://chesstempo.com/) wanted me to capture it with the queen:

```
[FEN "1r1r2k/p4pp/2q/2p1p2P/P1P1Pn/B3NP/4Q2P/R6K w - - 0 1"]

1. Nd5 Qxd5
2. cxd5 Nxe2
```

So, why do we play Qd5 instead of Rd5? Besides, does it matter for the White whether to play cxd5 or exd5 on the last board as the second move?

Comment: I think you've answered your own question. Look at the diagrams again

Comment: @David yep, that was a silly blunder which I didn't see for some reason :P.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After 1...Rxd5 2.cxd5, *both queens are attacked*. They either both get captured, or (if black moves his to safety) neither is. So black lost the exchange.

After 1...Qxd5 2.cxd5 Nxe2, white has lost a knight.

Cxd5 seems the better capture to me on general grounds (repairs white structure a bit, makes pawn c5 weaker) but that's far less important than the full rook difference between 1...Rxd5 and 1...Qxd5.